# Error: Can't set headers after they are sent - Correctly handling an error in an express controller

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have an issue with the below code. When an error is hit, the if statement is been hit and res.send is been called. However, the code then continues onto the res.json call below. This results in the headers error.

Is using an else statement the only correct way to do this? I would assume that calling res.send would break from the function.

```
exports.new = function (req, res) {
    let team = new Team();
    team.name = req.body.name;
    team.description = req.body.description;
    team.members = [];

    // save the team and check for errors
    team.save(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            res.status(400).send(err);
        }

        res.status(200).json({
            message: 'Team successfully created',
            team: team
        });
    });
};
```

I have also tried using req, res, next as the function parameters and using the following method:

```
if (err) {
    res.status(400);
    next(err);
}

res.status(200).json({
    message: 'Team successfully created',
    team: team
});
```

Whilst this doesn't throw an error, it still proceeds to call the final res.status.json (resulting in a 200, not a 400 response)

Comment: `res.send()` does *not* break, express chains the middleware handlers together using `next()` that is passed to `middleware(req, res, next)`. it is possible to call `res.send()` from multiple handlers, which is probably what is happening in your case.

Comment: Actually, you likely have an error and then try to set the headers/status after that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't send response after `res.end` is called, which is done internally by express when you call `res.send` function

In your case just add `return` when there's an error

```
if (err) {
    return res.status(400).send(err);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you don't return in that error case where you send status, so that code bellow just executes after anyway.

You need to write: `return res.status(400).send(err);`
or just use `if else`

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is incorrect about `res.send()` breaking, it will only do that if you `return`. Call `return` on `res.send()` in case of an error so that it does not continue. If you get an error it will set the status to 400 (in a header), then the error in the body, but because it does not return it then tries to set the status to 200 (in the header) causing the error you are seeing.

```
// save the team and check for errors
team.save(function (err) {
    if (err) {
        // return here so that it will not continue!
        return res.status(400).send(err);
    }

    // return here if there is no error!
    return res.status(200).json({
        message: 'Team successfully created',
        team: team
    });
});
```

Express chains middlewares together using `function(req, res, next)` and it is possible to return results via `res.send()` in multiple middlewares. The next middleware in the chain is called when you `return next()`, so if you wanted to return additional data in another middleware on success for example, would not `return res.send()` and instead call `return next()` after the `res.send()`.

Answer (score 0):

The error that you are getting is because the line of code

```
  res.status(200).json({
    message: 'Team successfully created',
    team: team
});
```

is being called whether it gets error or not . In case of the error the response header is already being sent in this  code by the express

```
if (err) {
    res.status(400).send(err);
}
```

So when the express tries the code below it gets the error that you expressed . The answer is to use the answer provided by Rami Jarrar

```
 // save the team and check for errors
team.save(function (err) {
    if (err) {
        res.status(400).send(err);
    }

    res.status(200).json({
        message: 'Team successfully created',
        team: team
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this:

```
team.save(function (err) {
    if (err) {
        return res.status(400).send(err); // here i have added a return
    }

    res.status(200).json({
        message: 'Team successfully created',
        team: team
    });
}
```

The problem is when we send the response to client the tcp connection will be closed and sending data on the same response object again will throw an error which you are getting in current code.